# How to get the sum of a column using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sum

php says it can't convert into int:

Notice: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\elearning\pages\student\upload.php on line 76:

```
              $userLoggedIn = $_SESSION['username'];

              $stmt = $conn->prepare(  "SELECT s.grade_level, s.section 
                                        FROM tblusers as u 
                                        JOIN tblstudents as s 
                                        ON u.username = s.username 
                                        WHERE u.username = :username" );
                                        $stmt->execute(array( ':username' => $userLoggedIn ));

              $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
              $filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
              $filepath = "../../assets/uploads/" . $file;

              $filelimit = $conn->prepare("SELECT SUM(f.filesize)
                                           FROM tblfiles AS f 
                                           JOIN tblstudents AS s
                                           ON f.uploader = s.username
                                           WHERE f.uploader = ':username'");
              $filelimit->execute(array(':username'=>$userLoggedIn));
```

this is line 76:  if($filelimit > 1048576)

Comment: there is no difference for getting a sum. You are getting it exactly the same way as any other data. To learn how to get data using PDO you **have** to follow a **tutorial**.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you have problem getting the value from `sum(f.filesize)` .

try give it an alias like that

```
  SELECT SUM(f.filesize) as filesize
```

and then retrieve the sum by this `filesize`

Comment: This is not the cause of the questioner's issue.  They are trying to read the PDOStatement object $filelimit as if it were the actual returned value of the query.

Answer (score 0):

`$filelimit` is a `PDOStatement` object. To get the result set you have to fetch the result set from the statement.

MrVimes has the complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

$filelimit is a PDO object.  Not an integer.  You need to get the result of the query from the object using `fetch()`

```
$row = $filelimit->fetch();

$filelimitvalue = $row[0];
```

and then in your if statement on line 76...

```
if($filelimitvalue > 1048576)
```

Comment: No problem.  It's an easy mistake to make when starting out with PDO.  Remember to accept one of the answers if you're happy with it.